# MVC5: Open URL from Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I know how to route a link to a controller, and I know how to open a URL from the view. But I don't know how to combine the two.

I would generally, keep the opening a URL logic inside the view, but I want to set some variables before I redirect, so I am looking for something that can open a URL from the controller. I want to set some session variables before redirecting to the URL.

So this is what I want:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me!", "HandleClick", "Controller", null, null)
```

And in m controller:

```
public ActionResult HandleClick()
{
    // Set Session variables
    // Open a URL
}
```

How can I do that? Also, is there any other better way to do this?

Note that the URL here is not a route, it is an external host like http://www.google.com

Comment: Looks like you are just looking for `return Redirect("http://www.google.com");` at the end of your method?

Comment: Thanks, that works! But it I want to open the URL in a new tab, not the same tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax.actionlink and javascript

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me!", "HandleClick", "Controller", new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "mySucess" });

    <script> 
        function mySuccess() {
            window.open('http://www.google.com/');
        }
    </scrip
```

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer did not worked for me. This is how I made it:

**in View:**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me!", "HandleClick", new { url = "www.google.com" }, null, new { @target = "_blank" })
```

Notes:

- **new {id = 1}**: It is just to demonstrate how to pass parameter to HandleClick if you have any parameter. You can use NULL, if there is no parameter to pass to your action
- **new { @target = "_blank" }**: Only specify if you want to open the link in new tab

**in Controler:**

```
public ActionResult HandleClick(string url)
{
    //TODO do any server-side operation
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

This will open a new tab and then redirects the new tab to the specified url.

No need to use JavaScript.